# css background image not loading, can't see the property in firebug at all

Tags: css, background-image

I am trying to create a simple landing page and my css backrgound-image is not loading.
This is the code I'm using

```
landing_container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    background: url("http://www.livingwatersshop.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Landing-Page-Background.jpg") 50%;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I tried local path, folder with relative path, with a ', with a ", but nothing loads.

When I check in the live editor here: http://scratchpad.io/selfish-education-2788
I can see the background no problem (I put in the full url) but when I upload to my website it still won't load.
I've tried chrome and firefox, deleted caching.

This is the link to the website: http://www.livingwatersshop.com/landy/index.html

Thanks in advance,
Maayan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<landing_container>` is a very bad custom tag. However, I see your problem that you are not shared here in your question, the problem is that your CSS files start with a `<style>` tag. That's totally wrong!

You have:

```
<style>
landing_container {
    ......
}
</style>
```

Just remove `<style>` and  `</style>` from the CSS files. That tags are only to include CSS inside an HTML file.

When you remove that, your code will run perfectly.

## Edit:

I attach an image to demonstrate that if you remove that tags the background will show:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Oh wow, thanks! I totally copy pasted from the live editor and didn't notice... it works now (+ I changed the landing_container tag) thanks so much!

Comment: You must accept this answer as the correct answer. Check the tick below the voting buttons.

Comment: @MaayanNaveh are you here?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I seem to not be getting all the notifications.